# free() causing trouble when a child process frees memory

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<malloc.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
 int fd,fd1,fd2,fd3;
 int fork_id1,fork_id2,fork_id3;
 char *buffer =  NULL;
 char *buff = NULL;
 char *loc = NULL;
 int no_bytes_read = 0;
 int no_bytes_write = 0;
 int total_file_size = 0;
 int half_file_size = 0;
 int count = 0;
 int ret_val = 0;

 if(argc < 5){
  printf("Enter 1 i/p and 3 o/p files");
  return -1;
 }

 fd = open(argv[1],O_RDONLY);
 if(fd == -1){
  printf("\nRead file desc not created!\n");
  return -1;
 }

 total_file_size = lseek(fd,0,SEEK_END);
 half_file_size = (total_file_size / 2);
 lseek(fd,0,SEEK_SET);
 printf("\n Total File size is : %d \n",total_file_size);

 buffer = (char *)malloc((sizeof(char) * total_file_size));
 if(buffer == NULL){
  printf("\n Cant allocate memory for buffer \n");
  return -1;
 }

 no_bytes_read = read(fd,buffer,total_file_size);

 fork_id1 = fork();
if(fork_id1 == 0){

  fd1 = open(argv[2],O_WRONLY);
  if(fd1 == -1){
   printf("\n write file des for child1 not created!\n");
   return -1;
  }

  buff = (char *)malloc((sizeof(char) * half_file_size));
  if(buff == NULL){
   printf("\n buff not created for child1 \n");
   return -1;
  }
  loc = buff;

  for(count = 0; count <= half_file_size; count++){
   *buff++ = *buffer++;
  }
  buff = loc;

  no_bytes_write = write(fd1,loc,half_file_size);
  free(buff);
  buff = NULL;
 }
 else{
  wait();
  fork_id2 = fork();
  if(fork_id2 == 0){

   fd2 = open(argv[3],O_WRONLY);
   if(fd2 == -1){
    printf("\n write file des not created for child2 \n");
    return -1;
   }

   buff = (char *)malloc((sizeof(char) * half_file_size));
   if(buff == NULL){
    printf("\n buff not created for child1 \n");
    return -1;
   }
   loc = buff;

   for(count = half_file_size+1 ; count <= total_file_size; count++){
    *buff++ = buffer[count];
}
   buff = loc
   no_bytes_write = write(fd2,loc,half_file_size);
   free(buff);
  }
  else{
   wait();
   fork_id3 = fork();
   if(fork_id3 == 0){

    fd3 = open(argv[4],O_WRONLY);
    if(fd3 == -1){
     printf("\n write file des not created for child3 \n");
     return -1;
    }

    buff = (char *)malloc((sizeof(char)* total_file_size));
     if(buff == NULL){
      printf("\n buff not created for child1 \n");
      return -1;
     }
     loc = buff;

     for(count = 0 ; count <= total_file_size; count++){
      *buff++ = *buffer++;
     }
     buff = loc;
     no_bytes_write = write(fd3,loc,total_file_size);
     free(buff);
   }
   else{
     wait(); //TODO
     //free(buffer);
     printf("\n Parent \n");
     /* To compare the files */
     //ret_val = validate(argv[1],argv[2],argv[3],argv[4],total_file_size);
     //if(ret_val == -1){
     // return -1;
     //}
   }
  }
 }
 return 0;
}
```

I am copying entire file in a buffer and copying the 1st half of the bytes to file A, 2nd half of the bytes to file B and the complete contents to file C. In each child i'm allocating memory for the temporary buffer, when i tried to free i get a segmentation fault.

Comment: The seg fault means you've abused the memory, somehow.  There's at least one bug in your code.  Most probably, you're overwriting beyond the end of the allocated memory, or maybe writing before the start of allocated memory.  Have you got `valgrind`?  If so, use it; it makes tracking the problem easy (provided you compile with the `-g` option).

Comment: Note that your second child uses `O_WRONLY` without `O_APPEND` so it truncates the first half of the file and then writes its new data.  Your copying operations are unnecessary, too.  You could use: `write(fd2, buffer, half_file_size)` and `write(fd3, buffer + half_file_size, total_file_size - half_file_size)`.

Comment: @Jonathan : yeah. I should not have used that extra buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the reason:

```
 for(count = 0; count <= half_file_size; count++){
   *buff++ = *buffer++;
  ...
  free(buff);
```

Your loop is changing the pointer you allocated the memory with. You can only use `free` on a pointer with the original value returned by `malloc`.

Comment: Yours is by far the better answer here +1

Comment: Thanks. i set the buff = loc(to the start of the buffer). and freed the buff. its working fine

Comment: @Angus - you don't need to use the same pointer as used with `malloc`, just a pointer with the same value, so `free(loc)` would have done the job too.